# Dual Frame Buffer on Ubuntu 12.04 Intel HD Graphics 4600 i7-4770

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, dualhead, framebuffer

I have 2 monitors connected to the PC, one in HDMI, one in DVI. I have Intel integrated graphics HD4600

Now as far my understanding, both the monitors is connected at the same framebuffer `/dev/fb0`

How can I detach them and create 2 frame buffers at startup, so that I can directly write to the second monitor, by writing on the `/dev/fb1`, and not hamper the `/dev/fb0`, so that X-server can run normally on that?

Comment: When you say "so that X-server can run normally on **that**?" is **that** the second, or the first?

Comment: I mean that x-server should run on the primary monitor as it is, but secondary monitor can be used to directly write data on the framebuffer.